# User Jquery to determine online/offline status

Tags: jquery, offline, yahoo-api

i am currently building a website and was relying on php fetch_content to read file this (http://opi.yahoo.com/online?u=yahooid&m=a&t=1) and it returns 00 for offline and 01 for online. Somehow i moved my hosting n the new hosting can't do php_fetch_content, is there is any way for jQuery to do this? 
i've tried .get() and don't really know hos it works, so it turns out not working. Any help would be very appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot use AJAX due to [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restrictions, unless the server supports [JSONP](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/).